# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 UserName display name

Tags: c#, asp.net

I installed the Identity 2.0 Sample Project: **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre**.

I want to specify a display name for the UserName field so it displays *Nombre de Usuario* (in Spanish) instead of *UserName* using `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)`. I went to the definition for the model.

`ApplicationName.Models.ApplicationUser : IdentityUser : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IUser, IUser<string>`.

In the last definition, I have `public virtual string UserName { get; set; }` but I cannot edit that file to add `[Display(Name="Nombre de Usuario")]`. Where should I add it?